# Functions for constructing Flow types?

Tags: flowtype

Is there any way I can do something like this:

```js
// @flow
function FailureActionType(name: string): Type {
  return {type: name, error: string}
}

type SearchFailureAction = FailureActionType("SEARCH_FAILURE")
```

Obviously there's problems in the way the typing/assignments are written in the return statement, but it would work such that

```
type SearchFailureAction = { type: "SEARCH_FAILURE", error: string }
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a generic.

```js
type FailureActionType<T: string> = { type: T, error: string }
```

- The `<T>` there says that this type is dependent on another type.
- `<T: string>` means this dependent type must be a type of string.
- `{ type: T, error: string }` means the resulting type must have the dependant type on the `type` key of the object.

You use it by passing in a value for `T` in <> like so:

```js
type SearchFailureAction = FailureActionType<"SEARCH_FAILURE">

const action1: SearchFailureAction = { type: 'SEARCH_FAILURE', error: 'some error' }
const action2: SearchFailureAction = { type: 'BAD', error: 'some error' } // type error
```

[flow.org/try Proof](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYghgSwDYFcBOECCBjYCD2AdgCrgQA8xAXFAM7BoKEDmAfFALxQDeUokNYgBooENGnxoa9RiygBfAFD9oAZQhw02ABbxk6LLgKFOsRKgw48RUpHIAiVQFFMAJQDCACQD6MTAEkAGQBVVyd7VkVFbCJ6KDgjIgBGGnVNHT0LQ2sTLl4VGgByZzcvXwCQsMKRMQkpKELafABbaFrJQoVo2OB4xMIAJlSNLV1zAytjU3yyIoAhTAARatFxSSKm1tW6zvkoAHp9vjJtySA)

---

Generics are pretty powerful. Read the docs for more.
https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/